# Rails - How to query by multiple ids(array)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

In rails 4, I am trying to access a ActiveRecord relation using multiple ids.

Ids are coming as `Parameters: {"ids"=>"[55, 56]"}`. In controller I am using it as `User.where(:id=>params[:ids])` but this query returns zero results.

View path is like `user_posts_path(:ids=>[5, 6])`

Right now `params[:ids].class.name` is `String`. How to make it only as an array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
User.where(id: JSON.parse(params[:ids]))
```

But I'd try to pass these ids as an array, not an array in a string, if possible.

Comment: Thank You. It is working fine. I am passing it as an array only but it is taking as a string inside the params.

Answer (score 2):

Rails has a built in notation to pass arrays through the query string.

```
Started GET "/users?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3" for ::1 at 2016-08-19 12:08:42 +0200
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"ids"=>["1", "2", "3"]}
```

When you use `some_key[]=1&some_key[]=2` notation Rails will merge all the `some_key` parameters into an array.

Passing a array to the path helper will generate the correct request URL.

```
irb(main):012:0> app.users_path(ids: [1,2,3])
=> "/users?ids%5B%5D=1&ids%5B%5D=2&ids%5B%5D=3"
# for clarity
irb(main):013:0> CGI.unescape app.users_path(ids: [1,2,3])
=> "/users?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3"
```

Using `JSON.parse` is just masking a bug in your application with a hacky fix.

What is most likely going wrong in your case is that the input to `users_path(ids: some_variable)` is a string and not an array as expected.

```
irb(main):014:0> CGI.unescape app.users_path(ids: "[1,2,3]")
=> "/users?ids=[1,2,3]" # this will not be treated as an array!
```

- https://coderwall.com/p/uh8kiw/pass-arrays-objects-via-querystring-the-rack-rails-way

Answer (score 0):

Something worth noting about the answers above: They do not maintain order, and they do not retrieve duplicates. To maintain order, newer Rails versions allow the following:

```
User.find(32, 12, 4,2,1,2,5).map(&:id)
=> [32, 12, 4, 2, 1, 5]
```

I'm not aware of any way to re-insert the duplicates back beyond manually re-populating the list.